# Symfony 5: ManyToMany Relationship Not Persisting When Added from MappedBy Side Without 'by_reference' => false

Tags: forms, entity-relationship, symfony5, mappedby

##### Context:

I'm working on a Symfony 5 application with entities **`InventaireActif`** and **`TypeActif`** having a ManyToMany relationship. An issue arises when managing this relationship through a Symfony form.

##### Problem:

In my form for **`TypeActif`**, when I add **`InventaireActif`** entities, they are not persisted to the database unless I set the **`'by_reference' => false`** option in the form builder. I want to achieve the correct behavior without relying on this option.

##### Entity Configuration:

**InventaireActif.php:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=TypeActif::class, inversedBy="lesActifs")
 */
private $lesTypesActifs;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->lesTypesActifs = new ArrayCollection();
    // ... other initializations ...
}

/**
 * @return Collection<int, TypeActif>
*/
public function getLesTypesActifs(): Collection
    {
        return $this->lesTypesActifs;
    }

    public function addLesTypesActif(TypeActif $lesTypesActif): self
    {
        if (!$this->lesTypesActifs->contains($lesTypesActif)) {
            $this->lesTypesActifs[] = $lesTypesActif;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeLesTypesActif(TypeActif $lesTypesActif): self
    {
        $this->lesTypesActifs->removeElement($lesTypesActif);

        return $this;
    }
```

**TypeActif.php:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=InventaireActif::class, mappedBy="lesTypesActifs")
 */
private $lesActifs;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->lesActifs = new ArrayCollection();
    // ... other initializations ...
}

public function getLesActifs(): Collection
{
    return $this->lesActifs;
}

public function addLesActif(InventaireActif $lesActif): self
{
    if (!$this->lesActifs->contains($lesActif)) {
        $this->lesActifs[] = $lesActif;
        $lesActif->addLesTypesActif($this);
    }
    return $this;
}

public function removeLesActif(InventaireActif $lesActif): self
{
    if ($this->lesActifs->removeElement($lesActif)) {
        $lesActif->removeLesTypesActif($this);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

##### Form Configuration in TypeActifType.php:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
{
    $builder
        // ... other fields ...
        ->add('lesActifs', EntityType::class, [
            'required' => false,
            'class' => InventaireActif::class,
            'choice_label' => 'libelle',
            // 'by_reference' => false,
            'multiple' => true,
            'query_builder' => function (InventaireActifRepository $repo) {
                return $repo->lesActifsReformesSortedASC();
            },
        ]);
}
```

##### edit route in TypeActifController.php:

```
public function new(Request $request, TypeActifRepository $typeActifRepository, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
    {
        $typeActif = new TypeActif();
        $form = $this->createForm(TypeActifType::class, $typeActif);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $typeActifRepository->add($typeActif, true);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_type_actif_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
        }

        return $this->renderForm('type_actif/new.html.twig', [
            'type_actif' => $typeActif,
            'form' => $form,
        ]);
    }
```

##### Issue with 'by_reference':

- When **`'by_reference' => false`** is uncommented, the form works perfectly, and the ManyToMany relationship is updated as expected.
- However, I want to avoid using **`'by_reference' => false`**. Without this option, adding **`InventaireActif`** entities through the **`TypeActif`** form does not persist the changes.

##### Attempts to Resolve:

- Ensured **`add`** and **`remove`** methods in both entities are synchronized.
- Reviewed Doctrine configurations and annotations.

##### Expected Behavior:

The changes should be saved to the database when **`InventaireActif`** entities are added via the **`TypeActif`** form, without needing to set **`'by_reference' => false`**.

##### Current Behavior:

Without **`'by_reference' => false`**, the changes are not persisted. No error is displayed, and the logs show nothing out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `by_reference` is set to `true` (or is ommitted), Symfony's form system simply adds the selected entities to the specified property using the methods of the `ArrayCollection` class. If `by_reference` is set to `false`, it uses the custom add/remove methods you specified instead.

And when saving the entity to the database, only changes made to the **owning** side of the ManyToMany relationship are saved. The owning side in your code is the `$lesTypesActifs` property in the `InventaireActif` class.

In your form, without `by_reference = false`, you're only updating the `$lesActifs` property of a `TypeActif` entity, which is the **inverse** side of the relationship, so that's why the changes are not being saved. But if you add `by_reference = false`, the custom add/remove methods make sure the owning side is also updated, so then the changes are saved.

I'm not sure if you also have a form that updates the `InventaireActif` entity by modifying its `$lesTypeActif` property, but if you do not, you could probably just switch the owning and inverse sides of your entities to get rid of `by_reference = false`:

```
class TypeActif {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=InventaireActif::class, inversedBy="lesTypesActifs")
     */
    private $lesActifs;

    ...
}
```

---

```
class InventaireActif {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=TypeActif::class, mappedBy="lesActifs")
     */
    private $lesTypesActifs;

    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, because if I reverse the 'mappedBy' and the 'inversedBy' for the two entities, the problem is just reversed, i.e. if I modify 'lesTypesActifs' from the 'InventaireActif' form, it doesn't work anymore, the changes are no longer taken into account. But now I can remove the 'by_reference => false' in the TypeActif.php form.

Comment: If you also have an `InventaireActif` form than you can't solve the problem by swapping the owning and inverse sides. In that case you do have to keep using `by_reference`, at least in one of the forms.